# Why I`m getting this TypeError?

Tags: python, database, discord.py

I am trying to create a getprefix command, which changes the server prefix. I`m using an sql database to store prefixes. I am getting the following error when I send any message in a server, not only bot commands:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 835, in get_prefix
    ret = list(ret)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 975, in process_commands
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 886, in get_context
    prefix = await self.get_prefix(message)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 842, in get_prefix
    raise TypeError("command_prefix must be plain string, iterable of strings, or callable "
TypeError: command_prefix must be plain string, iterable of strings, or callable returning either of these, not NoneType
```

My code:

```
def get_prefix(bot, message):
    prefix = db.field("SELECT Prefix FROM guilds WHERE GuildID = ?", message.guild.id)
    return when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)
```

My database code:

```
from os.path import isfile
from sqlite3 import connect

from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

DB_PATH = "./data/db/database.db"
BUILD_PATH = "./data/db/build.sql"

cxn = connect(DB_PATH, check_same_thread=False)
cur = cxn.cursor()


def with_commit(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        commit()

    return inner


@with_commit
def build():
    if isfile(BUILD_PATH):
        scriptexec(BUILD_PATH)


def commit():
    cxn.commit()


def autosave(sched):
    sched.add_job(commit, CronTrigger(second=0))


def close():
    cxn.close()


def field(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    if (fetch := cur.fetchone()) is not None:
        return fetch[0]


def record(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    return cur.fetchone()


def records(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    return cur.fetchall()


def column(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    return [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]


def execute(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))


def multiexec(command, valueset):
    cur.executemany(command, valueset)


def scriptexec(path):
    with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as script:
        cur.executescript(script.read())
```

The first time I`ve tried this it worked perfectly with the same code: I was able to update custom prefixes for servers in the database without any errors.

Comment: where are you defining ```ret```?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because the fetch variable is None, because cur.fetchone() returns None (no data retrieved from the database), therefore that function skips the if and return None

```
def field(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    if (fetch := cur.fetchone()) is not None:
        return fetch[0]
```

is equivalent to

```
def field(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    if (fetch := cur.fetchone()) is not None:
        return fetch[0]
    else:
        return None  # Causing the error
```

I think it might come from the `tuple(values)`, the variable `value` is actually already a tuple as you can see in this example, showing that you don't need to call `tuple()` on your parameter. Try without tuple it might work

```
>>> def foo(*a):
...     print(tuple(a))
...
>>> foo(5,6)
(5, 6)
>>>
>>> def bar(*a):
...     print(a)
...
>>> bar(5,6)
(5, 6)
>>>
```

Comment: I`ve tried and nothing changed..

Comment: Then the issue might be that your database doesn't have any data matching the query. Also you could try with `%s` instead of `?` in your query string
Or finally you can try wrapping your message.guild.id in a tuple like so `... = ?", tuple(message.guild.id)` or `... = ?", (message.guild.id, ) )` (the coma is not a typo)

Comment: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Comment: and with the last solution i get this: `prefix = db.field("SELECT Prefix FROM guilds WHERE GuildID = %s", tuple(message.guild.id))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Well forget the %s then, same goes for the tuple(message.guild.id), it must be dependant on your SQL library. My answer won't help you then :/